# How can I fix a Paragraph at the end of all my Pdf pages using

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext, pdf-generation

I am generating a receipe pdf and I am using this way to put data into it:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        paragraph.add(new Chunk(data.getPageLayout().getPrescription(), new Font(Font.BOLD, 24, Font.HELVETICA)));
        doc.add(paragraph);
```

But now I want to put a Paragraph in the end of all pages, like a default disclaimer, how can I do it?

Comment: Content that is not part of the body but instead like page headers or footers can be added in page event listeners. I'd propose looking for examples of them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. You can replace the header/footer text with whatever paragraph you want and change its co-ordinates.

```
import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.TextAlignment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextFooter {
public static final String DEST = "./target/sandbox/events/text_footer.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    new TextFooter().manipulatePdf(DEST);
}

protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new TextFooterEventHandler(doc));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Test " + (i + 1)));
        if (i != 2) {
            doc.add(new AreaBreak());
        }
    }

    doc.close();
}


private static class TextFooterEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    protected Document doc;

    public TextFooterEventHandler(Document doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event currentEvent) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) currentEvent;
        Rectangle pageSize = docEvent.getPage().getPageSize();
        PdfFont font = null;
        try {
            font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // Such an exception isn't expected to occur,
            // because helvetica is one of standard fonts
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        float coordX = ((pageSize.getLeft() + doc.getLeftMargin())
                + (pageSize.getRight() - doc.getRightMargin())) / 2;
        float headerY = pageSize.getTop() - doc.getTopMargin() + 10;
        float footerY = doc.getBottomMargin();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(docEvent.getPage(), pageSize);
        canvas

                // If the exception has been thrown, the font variable is not initialized.
                // Therefore null will be set and iText will use the default font - Helvetica
                .setFont(font)
                .setFontSize(5)
                .showTextAligned("this is a header", coordX, headerY, TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .showTextAligned("this is a footer", coordX, footerY, TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .close();
    }
}
```

}